# Call another activity from childrow, expandable listview, filter

Tags: java, android, android-activity, filter, expandablelistview

I would like to make an expandable list On clicking on an option take me to another activity. At the moment I only managed to make a message appear. I have only a few childrow, but I want to add more and they all take me to different activities

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.gerardoalberto.lmx;

import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, SearchView.OnCloseListener {

    private SearchManager searchManager;
    private android.widget.SearchView searchView;
    private MyExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    private ExpandableListView myList;
    private ArrayList<ParentRow> parentList = new ArrayList<ParentRow>();
    private ArrayList<ParentRow> showTheseParentList = new ArrayList<ParentRow>();
    private MenuItem searchItem;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

        parentList = new ArrayList<ParentRow>();
        showTheseParentList = new ArrayList<ParentRow>();

        //The app will crash if display list is not called here.
        displayList();

        //This expands the list of continents.
        expandAll();
    }

    private void loadData() {
        ArrayList<ChildRow> childRows = new ArrayList<ChildRow>();
        ParentRow parentRow = null;

        childRows.add(new ChildRow(R.mipmap.generic_icon,"Charlie."));
        childRows.add(new ChildRow(R.mipmap.generic_icon,"James."));
        childRows.add(new ChildRow(R.mipmap.generic_icon,"Carlos."));
        childRows.add(new ChildRow(R.mipmap.generic_icon,"Alphonse."));
        childRows.add(new ChildRow(R.mipmap.generic_icon,"Amelia."));
        childRows.add(new ChildRow(R.mipmap.generic_icon,"Olivia."));
        parentRow = new ParentRow("Names", childRows);
        parentList.add(parentRow);

        childRows = new ArrayList<ChildRow>();
        childRows.add(new ChildRow(R.mipmap.generic_icon,"Arcane"));
        childRows.add(new ChildRow(R.mipmap.generic_icon,"Fire."));
        parentRow = new ParentRow("Magic", childRows);
        parentList.add(parentRow);

        childRows = new ArrayList<ChildRow>();
        childRows.add(new ChildRow(R.mipmap.generic_icon,"red"));
        childRows.add(new ChildRow(R.mipmap.generic_icon,"Yellow."));
        parentRow = new ParentRow("Color", childRows);
        parentList.add(parentRow);
    }

    private void expandAll() {
        int count = listAdapter.getGroupCount();
        for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
            myList.expandGroup(i);
        }
    }

    private void displayList() {
        loadData();

        myList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView_search);
        listAdapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter(MainActivity.this, parentList);

        myList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        searchView.setOnCloseListener(this);
        searchView.requestFocus();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onClose() {
        listAdapter.filterData("");
        expandAll();
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        listAdapter.filterData(query);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        listAdapter.filterData(newText);
        return false;
    }
}
```

**MyExpandableListAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.gerardoalberto.lmx;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by GerardoAlberto on 10/04/2016.
 */
public class MyExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<ParentRow> parentRowList;
    private ArrayList<ParentRow> originalList;

    public MyExpandableListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ParentRow>originalList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.parentRowList = new ArrayList<>();
        this.parentRowList.addAll(originalList);
        this.originalList = new ArrayList<>();
        this.originalList.addAll(originalList);
    }
    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return parentRowList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return parentRowList.get(groupPosition).getChildList().size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return parentRowList.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return parentRowList.get(groupPosition).getChildList().get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ParentRow parentRow = (ParentRow) getGroup(groupPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.parent_row, null);
        }
        TextView heading = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.parent_text);

        heading.setText(parentRow.getName().trim());
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ChildRow childRow = (ChildRow) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        if(convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_row, null);
        }

        ImageView childIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.child_icon);
        childIcon.setImageResource(R.mipmap.generic_icon);

        final TextView childText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.child_text);
        childText.setText(childRow.getText().trim());

        final View finalConvertView = convertView;
        childText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(finalConvertView.getContext(), childText.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

    public void filterData(String query) {
        query = query.toLowerCase();
        parentRowList.clear();

        if (query.isEmpty()) {
            parentRowList.addAll(originalList);
        }
        else {
            for (ParentRow parentRow : originalList) {
                ArrayList<ChildRow> childList = parentRow.getChildList();
                ArrayList<ChildRow> newList = new ArrayList <ChildRow>();

                for (ChildRow childRow: childList) {
                    if (childRow.getText().toLowerCase().contains(query)){
                        newList.add(childRow);
                    }
                } //end for (childRow childRow: childList)
                if (newList.size() > 0) {
                    ParentRow nParentRow = new ParentRow(parentRow.getName(),newList);
                    parentRowList.add(nParentRow);
                }
            } //end for (ParentRow parentRow : originalList)
        } //end else

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: So instead of toasting in your `onClick(View)` start an intent from your context. It's pretty easy actually, you'll facepalm for asking once you look it up :)

Comment: thank you for answer my question. The problem is that i dont know how to do that, i take the code from a tutorial. Can you tell me how to do that, start an intent from my context or where can i find information about that. And again ty for answer and sorry for my english :)